# I want to copy data from one table into another table within the same database and one id also

Tags: php, mysql

I have fired the query

```
mysql_query(
       insert into temp_data
      (test_id,subject,unit,ques,options,right_opt,marks)
       select test_id,subject,unit,ques,options,right_opt,marks
       from questions where test_id='$test_id');
```

but there is one more `column stu_id` in `temp_data table` whose value is stored in `$stu_id` variable.

**My problem** is i want to insert the stu_id column value as $stu_id and remaining column values from the another table as shown in query

Comment: why you are storing `stu_id`  value in other variable??

Comment: Update temp_data set stu_id = $stu_id where test_id = $test_id  after insert statement

Comment: the question table dosnt have the stu_id column and  temp_data has it so thats why i have to store the value in another variable whose value should also get inserted while inserting the question table value

Comment: Is there any relation between temp_data.stu_id and questions.test_id or    temp_data.stu_id and temp_data.test_id

Comment: No there is no relation between this, actually test is not assign to partcular student id .question table will only consist of test id and  $stu_id will be fetched from student details table when particular student will login and its session id will be stored in$stu_id variable

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what you are trying to do can you b more specific with the question?
if you are trying to insert certain rows from one table to another, there are certain things you can do:
1) if you are trying to insert the same values while inserting you can create a trigger in the database and insert only the wanted rows to the next table when insert in 1st table is done
2)you can just dump the data and run the dumped data to another table

Comment: i just want to insert the stu_id column value of temp_data from another variable i.e. $stu_id and remaining column values of temp_data table from question table simultaneously